# What does SET_CONFIGURATION actually do in USB device?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

According to protocol SET_CONFIGURATION should apply the selected configuration and enable the device.

By 'enable the device', does it mean USB device firmware should enable and bring up all endpoints associated with the configuration descriptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember - yes after SET_CONFIGURATION firmware needs to enable all the selected endpoints and starts to responding for incoming requests.